# Synonym Search Using Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx, php-5.3

Has somebody written a morphology engine for synonyms on sphinx.  Or is the best bet still to create a [word forms](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.8.html#conf-wordforms) dictionary which declares all my synonyms.  Also how will this affecting stemming.  In the documentation it states:

> stemming is not applied to words found
>   in the forms list

Does this mean that if I have defined running > run in my wordform that runs will not be stemmed to run because run appears in my word forms list?

Answer (score 2):

You can create synonyms in mongo or mysql for example, and do query preporcessing, so when somebody do search with:

> Cola

you will change the query to:

> (cola|pepsi|sprite)

which allow you to do morphology search on those words, because stemming doesn't apply to word-forms as you have mentioned.